# Creating exe file with pdf output

Tags: compiling

We have this latex file which we change frequently. What we usually do is:

- go to line 51 and replace **bio 101** with **bio 102**
- go to line 103 and replace **midterm** with **final**
- go to line 184 and replace **summer 2016** with **fall 2016**

and etc. So, I was wondering, instead of doing that, is it possible to make an .exe file (possibly in c) asking:

- Class?
- Press M for midterm, F for final.
- Year?
- Semester? Press 1 for fall, 2 for spring, 3 for summer.

then creating a pdf output.

Comment: You don't need an exe-file, latex can also run interactively. But I would simply put a \newcommand\class{bio 102} in the preamble, and use \class in the document. Then all changes can be done in the preamble.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer can you please make an answer?

Comment: I would make those details change automatically as function of the compilation date (current date) as it seems there is a logic in the above stated mods that need to be made in the source file.

Comment: See [Importing Parameters From a Separate File](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294117) for a variety of ways to do this sort of thing.

Comment: See also [this answer using \typein](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53129/106253) to prompt the user for input during compilation

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an .exe or some external processor, latex can also run interactively.

But I would simply put a `\newcommand\class{bio 102}` in the preamble, and use `\class` in the document and so on. Then all changes can be done in the preamble.

Comment: a related approach, requiring some rewriting now, is to remove the `\documentclass` line, place it in a separate file, add the `\class` (and related) definition(s), followed by an `\input` of the file with the text.  then only the small "driver" file needs to be touched unless there's a real change to the main text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I can think of many approaches, one can also put the data in some csv-file, or calculate it, or ... But as the question is quite vage, I don't intent to elaborate. I wouldn't have answered anyway if touhami hadn't pinged me.