# Usage of TeX in unnatural fields

Tags: tex-general

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX in Industry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40720/latex-in-industry)
>   [In what ways can TeX be used beyond document production?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/in-what-ways-can-tex-be-used-beyond-document-production)

TeX has limited usage: mathematics, physics, linguistics, chemistry, biology, most of which is a branch of science.

I'm interested in usage of TeX in any unnatural fields: newspapers, advertisements etc.

Comment: Maybe related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [LaTeX in Industry](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40720/5764); [In what ways can TeX be used beyond document production?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53082/5764)

Comment: @Werner: you beat me by 10 seconds. `:)`

Comment: Novels? Poetry books?

Comment: Related: [_I'm using (La)TeX mainly for..._ poll](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1572/11002). Notice the numerous votes for "writing letters".

Comment: Have you seen this one: [I TeX Therefore I Toast](http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/i-tex-therefore-i-toast/)

Comment: Seeing how many comments are there, it seems that we agreed that the statement _"TeX has limited usage"_ is not so true.

Comment: although it does have some math/technical content, that's not the point of [this book](http://www.treesmapsandtheorems.com/pdfs/TM&Th-samplepages.pdf) by jean-luc doumont.  these sample pages show some of the things that tex can do (though one has to work at it a bit).