# Draw block diagram based on schemabloc or blox package

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Related to this question [Drawing a closed loop diagram with Tikz with multiple inputs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/318762/92620). I am trying to draw that diagram based essentially on [**`schemabloc`**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/schemabloc) package (french macros names and docs), I don't think the package itself is enough flexible to allow some adjustments. I would love to see that package improved.

Can some one draw it using that based on that package?

PS: I just noticed there is a similar package in english [**`blox`**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/blox).

[image]

What I am missing:

- Top right corner symbols (alpha, beta...)
- Links that are linked to only one bloc, the other end is an entry (like b2, c and d2), and probably a need to adjust the links b1, d1 because they are centered.
- The last segment from the link or path from D to A isn't straight and doesn't have an arrow.

here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning, quotes}
\tikzset{node distance= 5cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\sbEntree{E}

\sbBloc{A}{A}{E}
\sbBloc{B}{B}{A}
\sbRelier[$b_1$]{A}{B}

\sbSortie{S}{B}

\sbRelier[$c_1$]{B}{S}
\sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{S}{U}
\sbBlocr{C}{C}{U}
\sbRelieryx{B-S}{C}
\sbBlocr{D}{D}{C}
\sbRelier[$d_1$]{C}{D}

%\sbRelierxy{D}{E}
\draw [-] (D) -| node[name=D-E,near end,right] {} (E) ;
\draw (D) -| (E.south) node[below right] {};
\draw (E.south) -> (A) node {};

%\sbRelierxy{D-E}{A} %doesn't work
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit**

Based on [@crf's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318833#318836) I improved the code but still not complete you may need to read [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318833/draw-block-di-a-grams-based-on-schemabloc-or-blox-package#comment778815_318836):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  node distance=5cm,
  >=Stealth,
  every edge quotes/.append style={midway, below},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E}
  \sbBloc{A}{A}{E}
  \sbBloc{B}{B}{A}
  \sbRelier[$b_1$]{A}{B}
  \sbSortie{S}{B}

%\sbRelier[$c_1$]{B}{S}  %replaced with it tikz definition from doc, line below
\draw [sbStyleLien,auto] (B) -- node[name=B-S] {$c_1$} (S);  %add bullet ?

  \sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{S}{U}
  \sbBlocr{C}{C}{U}
  \sbRelieryx{B-S}{C}
  \sbBlocr{D}{D}{C}

%  \sbRelier[$d_1$]{C}{D} replace with it tikz definition from doc, line below:
\draw [sbStyleLien,auto] (C) -- node[name=C-D,above] {$d_1$} (D); %added the option "above"

  \draw [-] (D) -| (E) ;
  \draw (D) -| (E.south);
  \draw [->] (E.south) |- (A);
  \foreach \i/\j in {A/\alpha,B/\beta,C/\gamma,D/\omega} \node [anchor=north east, font=\scriptsize] at (\i.north east) {$\j$};
  \draw  ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=2.5mm]A.south east) coordinate (p1) edge ["$b_2$", ->] (B.west |- p1);
  \draw  ([xshift=-1.5mm,yshift=2.5mm] C.south west) coordinate (p2) edge ["$d_2$", ->] (D.east |- p2);
  \draw  ([xshift=-1.5mm,yshift=-2.5mm] C.east) coordinate (p3) edge ["$c$", ->] (C.west |- p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just to provide a basis for solving this. Since I don't read French, I've not tried to figure out the correct style of arrow etc. Just substitute appropriately for `Stealth` and drop `arrows.meta` if you don't need it.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  node distance=5cm,
  >=Stealth,
  every edge quotes/.append style={midway, below},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E}
  \sbBloc{A}{A}{E}
  \sbBloc{B}{B}{A}
  \sbRelier[$b_1$]{A}{B}
  \sbSortie{S}{B}
  \sbRelier[$c_1$]{B}{S}
  \sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{S}{U}
  \sbBlocr{C}{C}{U}
  \sbRelieryx{B-S}{C}
  \sbBlocr{D}{D}{C}
  \sbRelier[$d_1$]{C}{D}
  \draw [-] (D) -| (E) ;
  \draw (D) -| (E.south);
  \draw [->] (E.south) |- (A);
  \foreach \i/\j in {A/\alpha,B/\beta,C/\gamma,D/\omega} \node [anchor=north east, font=\scriptsize] at (\i.north east) {$\j$};
  \draw  ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=2.5mm]A.south east) coordinate (p1) edge ["$b_2$", ->] (B.west |- p1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: starter]

## EDIT

Here's a version with a couple more examples and tips from the deprecated `arrows` library to match `schemabloc`'s.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{schemabloc}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\tikzset{%
  node distance=5cm,
  every edge quotes/.append style={midway, below},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \sbEntree{E}
  \sbBloc{A}{A}{E}
  \sbBloc{B}{B}{A}
  \sbRelier[$b_1$]{A}{B}
  \sbSortie{S}{B}
  \sbRelier[$c_1$]{B}{S}
  \sbDecaleNoeudy[5]{S}{U}
  \sbBlocr{C}{C}{U}
  \sbRelieryx{B-S}{C}
  \sbBlocr{D}{D}{C}
  \sbRelier[$d_1$]{C}{D}
  \draw (D) -| (E.south);
  \draw [sbStyleLien] (E.south) |- (A);
  \foreach \i/\j in {A/\alpha,B/\beta,C/\gamma,D/\omega} \node [anchor=north east, font=\scriptsize] at (\i.north east) {$\j$};
  \draw  ([xshift=2.5mm,yshift=2.5mm]A.south east) coordinate (p1) edge ["$b_2$", sbStyleLien] (B.west |- p1);
  \draw ([xshift=-2.5mm,yshift=.5mm]C.south west) coordinate (p2) edge ["$d_2$",sbStyleLien] (D.east |- p2);
  \draw ([xshift=5mm,yshift=2.5mm]C.south east) coordinate (p3) edge [sbStyleLien] node [pos=0, anchor=west] {$c_2$} (C.east |- p3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: more egs]

Comment: After read you answer i tried something similiar to get d2 but it seems I am doing it wrong `\draw  ([xshift=0mm,yshift=2.5mm]C.south west) coordinate (p2) edge ["$d_2$", ->] (D.east |- p2);` sure the label d1 should goes on above the arrow. not bad but still b2 come beside the arrow and not under same for d2.

Comment: Does my example give you my output?

Comment: yes of course..without d2 and with b2 above the arrow instead of being beside it, without c too, in addition to label `a`.

Comment: I don't know why the label would come out beside. (Don't you want it there anyway? I put it under because that's where there seemed to be room, but your image in the question has it beside.)

Comment: maybe you're right under is better, actually i took that example as a challenge to train myself with that package syntax not more and not less so i am open to changes on the example itself. because i noticed that `schemabloc` is limited, as it's named it is supposed to guarantee the drawing of any schema bloc diagram and offrering some flexibility options.

Comment: Well, I didn't use the package at all. Only regular TikZ. As I said, I don't read French. The only use of the package here is from the code in your question.

Comment: Can you fix the remanning points that i have mentionned in previous comments? (i don't care if the labels are below the arrows instead of beside)

Comment: @cfr: How do you obtain the pstricks style of arrow tips with tikz? I very rarely use tikz, mainly with $tikz-cd$, and know it not well.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, but I don't know pstricks at all so I have no idea what style of arrow tips you're asking about.

Comment: @SAM I'm sorry, but I really don't know why you get labels beside the arrows rather than under them if you're using my code. As you can see, it works for me. Given the style definition, all labels given with `""` should use the settings by default.

Comment: @cfr: I mean the arrow tips you obtain. The default arrow tips look closely like the arrow tip  in, say, `\rightarrow`. Just look at the arrow tips in the O.P.'s question.

Comment: @Bernard Which ones? The ones drawn with the `schemabloc` I don't know how to match. The `Stealth` seemed close, so I used that for demonstration purposes. To get that, I'm loading `arrows.meta` which makes the `Stealth` tip available.

Comment: @cfr: Ah!  Thanks. I'll have to study some day these libraries. I must say pstricks seems so much easier to learn.

Comment: @Bernard The package is using the deprecated `arrows` library. Please see edit above. (It is using `>=latex`, I think.)

Comment: @SAM Please see edit. It works for me. (I put one beside using a different method in case you want that.)

Comment: That's nice it still two remanning how to put the label `a`, is it possible to add a bullet on the intersection of segments after `c1`?

Comment: In the conclusion the better is to avoid using this packages since it is old, not flexible and using deprecated libs right?

Comment: @SAM Not necessarily. But I don't read French, so I typically use packages documented solely in French very little.