# Tengwar script in TeX Live

Tags: fonts, texlive, languages, mapping

I tried to compile [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex/56440#comment118278_56440) example but the LaTeX compiler gives the following errors. What can I do?

```
name = tngani, rootname = tngani, pointsize = mktexmf: empty or non-existent rootfile!

Cannot find font tngani in map file(s).

kpathsea: Running mktexmf tngani.mf The command name is 
C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32\mktexmf Cannot find tngani.mf .
I try ps2pk --> gsftopk --> ttf2pk --> hbf2gf. ps2pk cannot be used.
I try gsftopk. gsftopk.exe tngani 1650 gsftopk cannot be used.
Next I try ttf2pk. ttf2pk.exe -q tngani 1650 ttf2pk failed.
Finally I try hbf2gf. hbf2gf.exe -q -p tngani 1650
All trials failed.
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 2+450/600 --dpi 1650 tngani
The command name is C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32\mktexpk 
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

Process exited with error(s)
```

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[annataritalic]{tengwarscript}

\begin{document}

\tengwarannataritalic[2.5]
\tengwa{254}
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tando\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tumbar\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tungwe\Tumbar\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\tengwa{255}\\
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tthuule\Troomen\Tquesse\TTthreedots\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedungwe\TTthreedots\Tumbar\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tesse\Tkern{-0.2}\Tmalta\TTrightcurl\Textendedcalma\TTdot\Ttelco\TTdot\Tquesse\Troomen\Tparma\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `tengwarscript` package provides only the metric files for the fonts, but not the fonts themselves which must be downloaded from the sites shown in the documentation.

You can, for instance, download the "Annatar" fonts from [here](http://www.dafont.com/tengwar-annatar.font) and unpack the ZIP file; then move the `.ttf` files in

```
C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\annatar
```

which should be

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/annatar
```

for a Unix system (create the necessary directories). Then a run of `mktexlsr` will make the font available. Add the declaration

```
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
```

just after the `\documentclass` line and the document should compile.

For other font families, look around on the net, for instance [here](http://www.fontspace.com/johan-winge/tengwar-annatar). Unfortunately, a link where several font families were available for download has disappeared.

Comment: I downloaded the font that you linked, and I put the ttf file here C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\Annatar I have created this directory: "truetype\Annatar" because did not exist. I use windows 8, I tried to compile the code I added in question but always the same error

Comment: @FormlessCloud Did you run `mktexlsr`? This should be done as Administrator, if you installed TeX Live in that way. I believe it can be done from `tlmgr`.

Comment: i have found mktexlsr.exe here C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32 i have run it as administrator but say error

Comment: I also want to ask you how i can translate in Italian the writing that I put in the question as imagine

Comment: "i have found mktexlsr.exe here C:\texlive\2011\bin\win32 i have run it as administrator but latex say the same error"

Comment: @FormlessCloud Sorry, I tried the procedure on my machine and it worked (but it's a Unix system). I don't have the least idea about the meaning of the text in any language. :)

Comment: The link to the Annatar fonts is broken. A very quick search shows [this link](http://www.dafont.com/tengwar-annatar.font) appears to work - I *think* it contains the fonts relevant to the question.

Comment: Missed the 5-minute edit allotment :( [This link](http://www.fontspace.com/johan-winge/tengwar-annatar) also contains the `tngani` ttf file. Perhaps one of those links is an appropriate replacement for the broken link?

Comment: @simont Thanks; unfortunately, links tend to disappear over time.

Comment: The linked font archive has some missing fonts. I used the fonts from here-->http://www.fontspace.com/download/2244/280a9b63cbfa4ca581ffbc45bd15d346/johan-winge_tengwar-annatar.zip

Comment: Sorry to resuscitate this, but I have followed the instructions, and even though the mktexlsr command worked, and I inserted the pdfmapfile line, I _still_ get "!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file tngani.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for reading"

Comment: @m4r35n357 Sorry, but there's no “official” support and if things go wrong…

Comment: OK cheers, I have posted a separate question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609862/installing-tengwar-fonts-in-linux in case anyone else can help.

Comment: @m4r35n357 You have to search for `tnganai.ttf`, which seems to be no longer distributed.

Comment: Hmm, that file is not in the error message . . . confusing!