# A package (installed according to TeX Live Utility) doesn't run

Tags: fonts, errors, installing, texlive

This is an example :

I've found here ([What package allows Elvish in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex)) that there existed a package called tengwarscript. I want to use it and when I used TeX Live Utility in order to download it, I saw that it was already installed...

However, it doesn't run and send me the error message

> !pdfTeX error: /usr/texbin/pdflatex (file tngani): Font tngani at 1650 not found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

I've also tried to install this package manually, by installing the file *tengwarscript* I found [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tengwarscript) in the file

/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex

but that didn't worked. I don't find any solution anywhere on stackexchange and don't understand all these instructions

> 1. "latex tengwarscript.dtx" to get the documentation.
> 2. "latex tengwarscript.ins" to get the package files.
> 3. a) Move *.sty and *.cfg into [TEXMF]/tex/latex/tengwarscript/.
>      b) Move *.tfm into [TEXMF]/fonts/tfm/tengwarscript/.
>      c) Move *.enc into [TEXMF]/fonts/enc/tengwarscript/.
>      d) Move *.vf into [TEXMF]/fonts/vf/tengwarscript/.
>      e) Move tengwarscript.map into [TEXMF]/fonts/map/dvips/.
> 4. Download the tengwar fonts (see documentation). You may need to
>      rename some files to match the names in the .map file.
> 5. Move *.ttf into [TEXMF]/fonts/truetype/tengwarscript/ or *.pfb
>      into [TEXMF]/fonts/type1/tengwarscript/.
> 6. Add "Map tengwarscript.map" to updmap.cfg.
> 7. "texhash" to refresh the database.
> 8. "updmap" or "updmap-sys" to update the configuration.

because I have no .sty file nor .cfg and so on...

Thank you for your help

Comment: As far as I remember, the package doesn't install the required fonts. I'll try finding more about this.

Comment: Here is the related question I was thinking to: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/tengwar-script-in-tex-live-2011

Comment: This doesn't  help me. I've done what is told in the "answer" but I can't run this example.