# Can I write Quenya using LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

Most of you must be aware of J. R. R.Tolkien, the author of "The Lord of the Rings". The author invented a language for one of the races(=Elves) in the LOTR universe, namely Quenya.

Of course this is a language on its own, but I was wondering if there is a way the output (the pdf file generated after compilation) of an English written essay, to be in Quenya characters.

Of course I do not mean a translation, just the change of characters.

Comment: perhaps this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56517/24834

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/tengwar-script-in-tex-live-2011?lq=1 give any help?

Comment: @JosephWright It seems that I have to write characters one by one plus the dots using that way. My question is if there is a way such that an English word to be automatically written in Quenya.

Comment: Panteli, can you give us a small example?  What do you want written in LaTeX and what to appear when typeset?  My ears are not very pointed and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quenya) doesn't help much.

Comment: The obvious answer is to just use a Quenya font that maps the characters TeX outputs (incl. ligatures, etc.) to Quenya characters.  Doesn't such a font exist?

Comment: @nickie It'so cool that I found a Greek person :). Say Nike that I want my name to be written in Quenya. I saw that there is a way to write it character by character (as in \Pi\alpha\nu\tau\epsilon\lambda\eta\varsigma). My questions asks for example if there is a way such that if I write "Pantelis" to actually get the Quenya characters after compilation.

Comment: @nickie Because Quenya also has its own alphabet someone should be able to use it [e.g., Pantelis (Latin) = Παντελής (Greek) ]

Comment: Right, but there is a character-to-character translation that you presume which I cannot follow, as the Quenya characters don't mean anything to me.  It would be the same for your "Pantelis" -> "Παντελής" example, for someone who did not know anything about the Greek alphabet and the way letters are pronounced in Greek.

Comment: BTW, I came accross [a page written by Ignacio Fernández Galván](http://djelibeibi.unex.es/tengwar/) which suggests using the `tengwarscript` LaTeX package and a Perl script called `ptt` for doing what you want.  I suppose you can do something similar directly in LaTeX, without the `ptt` script, but it will be tedious (the Perl script is 800 lines long).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea (if you want constructive feedback only) to start a question with a statement telling your readers what they should know. I was not aware of this Quenya language, and it escapes me why I _must_ know about it.

Comment: @Sverre I hope that the modification that I did, makes it better now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look to http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tolkienfonts ...  There is an extended documentation included.