# One ring inscription compiles but some characters are missing and the text is misplaced

Tags: fonts, errors

This isn't really work related but nevertheless an interesting obstacle I haven't been able to overcome by myself. I like to think of LaTex as *deus ex machina*, if you have the knowledge and the documentations you can do *anything* with it, including writing down the inscription of One ring from The Lord of The Rings. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[annataritalic]{tengwarscript}

\begin{document}

\tengwarannataritalic[1]
\tengwa{254}
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tando\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tumbar\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tungwe\Tumbar\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\tengwa{255}\    \Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tthuule\Troomen\Tquesse\TTthreedots\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedungwe\TTthreedots\Tumbar\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tesse\Tkern{-0.2}\Tmalta\TTrightcurl\Textendedcalma\TTdot\Ttelco\TTdot\Tquesse\Troomen\Tparma\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl

\end{document}
```

When I first tried to compile this code I ran into the same problem as most people. Package `tengwarscript` only provides basic metric scheme to the font, but not actual *encoding*. So I started looking for an answer in these forums and found one: [Tengwar script in TeX Live](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/tengwar-script-in-tex-live). I followed its instructions:

1. I downloaded and unzipped `.ttf` files
2. I placed them in this location: `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\truetype\annatar`
3. I *manually* installed every font (there is an 'install' button in every `.ttf` package)
4. I ran `mktexlsr.exe` as an administrator to make sure everything is updated

Then I compiled the above code again and got a weird result:
[image]

Can someone please explain me why this happened, and provide a fix? I'm very confused as my Texstudio reported `Process exited normally`. Can someone please help me? I thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the log file you've been asking for (this time with `\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}` included):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99996 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex 2016.11.11)  2 MAR 2017 11:45
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./Annatar.tex
(./Annatar.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
Package: expl3 2016/10/19 v6730 L3 programming layer (loader) 

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
Package: expl3 2016/10/19 v6730 L3 programming layer (code)
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2016/10/13 v6722 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2016/09/01 v6696 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2016/08/19 v6684 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2016/09/07 v6700 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count79
\l_tmpa_int=\count80
\l_tmpb_int=\count81
\g_tmpa_int=\count82
\g_tmpb_int=\count83
L3 Module: l3quark 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count84
L3 Module: l3clist 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2016/09/01 v6695 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2016/08/19 v6691 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count85
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count86
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count87
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count88
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count89
L3 Module: l3skip 2016/08/19 v6692 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen102
\c_max_dim=\dimen103
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen105
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen107
\c_zero_skip=\skip41
\c_max_skip=\skip42
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip43
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip44
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip45
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip46
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2016/09/21 v6711 L3 Key-value interfaces
\l_keys_choice_int=\count90
L3 Module: l3fp 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count91
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count92
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count93
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count94
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count95
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count96
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count97
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count98
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count99
L3 Module: l3box 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box26
\l_tmpa_box=\box27
\l_tmpb_box=\box28
\g_tmpa_box=\box29
\g_tmpb_box=\box30
L3 Module: l3coffins 2016/08/19 v6685 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box31
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen108
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen114
\c_empty_coffin=\box32
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box34
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box36
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen115
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen117
L3 Module: l3color 2016/06/13 v6596 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3candidates 2016/08/19 v6688 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen118
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_internal_box=\box40
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen126
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen132
L3 Module: l3luatex 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2016/08/18 v6679 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
\l__driver_tmp_box=\box41
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
Package: xparse 2016/10/19 v6730 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count100
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count101
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count102
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count103
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count104
)
Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
Package: fontspec-xetex 2016/02/01 v2.5a Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count105
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count106
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count107
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen133
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen135
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX package

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 105.


(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/euenc/eu1lmss.fd
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count108
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def
File: xetex.def 2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/
JK)
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen136
\Gin@req@width=\dimen137
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__fontspec_post_arg:w with sig. 'mmO{}' on line 353.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'om' on line 355.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'om' on line 365.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'om' on line 375.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'om' on line 385.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 399.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 407.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'om' on line 415.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'om' on line 423.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mom' on line 437.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mom' on line 453.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 467.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 529.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 540.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 548.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 556.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 577.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 586.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 590.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 594.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 599.
.................................................
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count109

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2705.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2710.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2715.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2720.
\l__fontspec_em_int=\count110
\l__fontspec_emdef_int=\count111
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 2736.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 2742.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 2746.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 2841.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 2845.
.................................................
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tengwarscript/tengwarscript.sty
Package: tengwarscript 2014/07/12 v1.3.1 TengwarScript for LaTeX

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13

`Basic Fixed Point Arithmetic',  Version 1.2d (C) Michael Mehlich             
\FP@xs=\count112
\FP@xia=\count113
\FP@xib=\count114
\FP@xfa=\count115
\FP@xfb=\count116
\FP@rega=\count117
\FP@regb=\count118
\FP@regs=\count119
\FP@times=\count120
) (c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05

`Fixed Point Snap Off',          Version 1.0a (C) Michael Mehlich             )
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tengwarscript/annataritalic.cfg))
(./Annatar.aux)
\openout1 = `Annatar.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 7.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 7.
[1]
(./Annatar.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
13647 strings out of 493589
271993 string characters out of 6146759
272936 words of memory out of 5000000
17054 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
4079 words of font info for 20 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1347 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
46i,4n,31p,10390b,233s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on Annatar.pdf (1 page).
```

EDIT 2: Here is error message when I try to run your recommended command (`updmap-sys --enable Map=tengwarscript.map`) in CMD:

[image]

I just wanted to say that I deeply appreciate your help. Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I *finally* managed to solve the problem. The crux was in the fact that TeXLive *isn't* my main source - the latter is MikTeX. That's why command Ulrike Fischer suggested didn't work. Because of his suggestion I went looking onto [this](https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html) page and found the right commands for MikTeX. I typed `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`, created a file with contents of `Map=tengwarscript.map` and then ran the command `initexmf --mkmaps` in CMD again. Furthermore, I tried to compile my One Ring code now, **and it worked.** I'd like to thank all of you for support and guidance, especially Ulrike Fischer and cfs. Thank you SO much!

[image]

Comment: Please show a picture of what is wrong in the current state (to make it easier for us).

Comment: I think I added a picture. Can you see it?

Comment: Works fine for me, but in texlive I had to add `\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}`. I used the fonts from here http://www.fontspace.com/johan-winge/tengwar-annatar. Show your log-file.

Comment: Oh yes, about that. I added `\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}` as well and ran Texstudio again. Nothing changed, the output was still the mess you can see above. Because of this result, I decided I'm not going to include `\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}` in my posted code. Help?

Comment: As I said: show the log file.

Comment: That's not the log of your example. It doesn't load fontspec. I doubt that the style will work with xelatex.

Comment: also you could update your texlive (there have been three latex releases since the version you show)

Comment: Oh really? Thank you I will (are there any big improvements?).

Comment: I wouldn't execute scripts in windows/system32 folder, and you have a typo in the name of the map, but beside this I can't tell you why updmap-sys can't write the new cfg. It *could* be that you need a command line with admin right, but as I don't have a multi user installation I can't test. You should ask the question on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: I am on Windows 10 as the *only* user so I have admin rights by default. I also ran CMD as administrator, but to no avail. I checked for a fix on other StackExchange forums, but found nothing useful. If you can, please help (because I love both LaTeX and Tolkien's works). Thank you (you are very kind and patient with me).

Comment: Does the file it can't read exist? Can you read it? I don't know anything about Windows. On another system, I would say you should check the file's ownership and permissions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 3 versions since 2016? Has the question been rewritten? If so, why do we still have a log for XeTeX?

Comment: You could try to create an (empty) updmap.cfg at the location where updmap has problems. But beside this I can only repeat my advice to ask on the texlive list https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live. There are quite kind and helpful people there.

Comment: To cfr: I have checked, the file `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\scripts\texlive\updmap.pl` does exist. I have Windows 10 and Kali Linux (with dualboot) if that helps you. On Windows I have Texstudio while on Kali Linux I have Texmaker.

Comment: @cfr  actually 4   releases. 2017/01/01, 2017/01/01 PL 1, 2017/01/01 PL2, 2017/01/01 PL3.

Comment: To Ulrike: thank you for all the help. Surely I'll seek further instructions in the source you've provided.

Comment: To cfr: all that is in `updmap.cfg` is: `Map tengwarscript.map`. How should I edit it manually. Please, help.

Comment: That's the file doing the reading - not the file it is trying to read. Don't worry about the `updmap.cfg` thing. It'll work Ulrike Fischer's way. It is just less persistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

texlive doesn't activate the map-file of the fonts. Compiling your example with pdflatex would give errors as pdflatex would not be able to find the ttf. xelatex can find the fonts but due to the missing map-file the encoding is wrong and so you get faulty/missing glyph.

To correct the problem for both engines call on a command line

```
 updmap-sys --enable Map=tengwarscript.map
```

Then a compilation with xelatex and pdflatex should work and give this

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, Ulrike, but the command always executes with error for some reason. Can I count on you (I'm very grateful for your help)? In case you're willing to help me further, I'll post the result of your command in my original post.

Comment: The recommended method is now to edit the local `updmap.cfg`, as I understand it. That is, that's what egreg said - unless they've changed the recommendation again, of course.

Comment: @cfr: The documentation says otherwise. Beside this: I tried it and it worked -- and I'm on windows.

Comment: I know it works. It works on other systems, too. As I understand it, the recommendation is based on the fact that local additions in TEXMFLOCAL then survive yearly editions.