# Installing tengwar fonts in Linux

Tags: linux

I have been following the accepted answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56487/tengwar-script-in-tex-live), but cannot get it to work.

Here is my font directory:

```
$ ls -lAh /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/annatar
total 940K
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 2.4K Apr  7  2004 readme.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 422K Aug  7 10:31 tengwar_annatar.zip
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  42K Apr  7  2004 tnganbi.ttf
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  41K Apr  7  2004 tnganb.ttf
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 338K Apr  7  2004 tngandoc.pdf
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  41K Apr  7  2004 tngani.ttf
-r--r--r-- 1 root root  40K Apr  7  2004 tngan.ttf
```

Here is the output of mktexlsr:

```
$ sudo mktexlsr
mktexlsr: Updating /usr/local/share/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXLIVEDIST... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R-TEXMFMAIN... 
mktexlsr: Updating /var/lib/texmf/ls-R... 
mktexlsr: Done.
```

Here is my test document:

```
$ cat tengwar.tex 
\documentclass{minimal}
\pdfmapfile{=tengwarscript.map}
\usepackage[annataritalic]{tengwarscript}

\begin{document}

\tengwarannataritalic[2.5]
\tengwa{254}
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tando\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tumbar\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tungwe\Tumbar\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\tengwa{255}\\
\Textendedcalma\TTthreedots\Tnuumen\Tessenuquerna\TTthreedots\Tungwe\Tthuule\Troomen\Tquesse\TTthreedots\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambealt\TTrightcurl\Tquesse\TTdoublerightcurl
\Tromanperiod\Ts
\Textendedungwe\TTthreedots\Tumbar\Toore\TTrightcurl\Tesse\Tkern{-0.2}\Tmalta\TTrightcurl\Textendedcalma\TTdot\Ttelco\TTdot\Tquesse\Troomen\Tparma\TTnasalizer\TTdot\Ttinco\TTthreedots\Tlambe\TTrightcurl
\end{document}
```

and here is the output of pdflatex:

```
$ pdflatex tengwar.tex 
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tengwar.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
){/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-d
ist/fonts/map/dvips/tengwarscript/tengwarscript.map}
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tengwarscript/tengwarscript.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
`Basic Fixed Point Arithmetic',  Version 1.2d (C) Michael Mehlich             )
 (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
`Fixed Point Snap Off',          Version 1.0a (C) Michael Mehlich             )
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tengwarscript/annataritalic.cfg))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def)
(./tengwar.aux) [1] (./tengwar.aux) ){/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/d
vips/tengwarscript/tengwarscript.enc}
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file tngani.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for r
eading
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Of course, I can cat tngani.ttf from the directory I am running pdflatex from, but I won't post the output here!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is the unmodified log output from running `pdflatex` on your file, in the setting that you describe? When I run your example, I also get an error, but it complains about `tnganai.ttf` being missing. The message in your log file complains about `tngani.ttf` being not found. The difference is that `tnganai.ttf` is indeed not in the font distribution, whereas `tngani.ttf` is.

This is how I was able to typeset your file.

1. Google for the missing `tnganai.ttf`. Among the offered locations, I downloaded the fonts from https://fontsdata.com/57983/johan-winge_tengwar-annatar.htm.
2. Proceed as you specified: unpack `johan-winge_tengwar-annatar.zip` to `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype/annatar` and run `mktexlsr`.
3. `pdflatex tengwar.tex`, et voilà ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Just to assure you, yes, everything I posted was cut'n'pasted directly from the console.  I will try your suggestion . . . .

Comment: OK I get the same "cannot open file" as before.  I guess something in my Latex/texlive setup is pointing to a wrong location (Ubuntu 20.04).  I don't have the chops to debug this stuff so I think I'll leave it for now (I will be installing Debian Bullseye over this soon).  Thanks again!

Comment: @m4r35n357 My guess is that you have multiple copies of some tengwar config file or tengwar fonts, or of the file specifying the fonts. Do you have several TeX installations? E.g., an old TeXlive version, or remnants of Ubuntus (La)TeX packages?

Comment: I am currently trying it on a Debian Buster setup to test this.  There was no tengwarscript on this system so I installed it through texlive-fonts-extra.  [UPDATE] [!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file tngani.ttf): cannot open TrueType font file for reading].  I have only one installation and haven't made any config changes, so I'll assume the package is broken.  Once again, I thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a good reason not to, use XeLaTeX, as per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169156/170418%5D) answer. The fonts you've installed should then work as expected.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!