# Elven font with TeX or LaTeX

Tags: fonts, languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What package allows Elvish in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex)

It is possible to write in elven language using TeX as it is on the background of this page?

Comment: No problem. Maybe it's better to keep the question (closed) nonetheless, as the name is different. I'm no expert in Tolkien's terminology, but it appears that both names, elvish and elven, are used.