# Inventing New Character for TeX

Tags: symbols, characters, extended-characters

how can I invent a new symbol/character for TeX.  For example, say I want to type the Tengwar letter ungwe (2 IV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tengwar_alphabet.png), or any other symbol that I can draw- how would I go about doing so.  I want to be able to use these diverse symbols as variables in a specific document that I am writing (which happens to be for a constructed language).

Note: I am not specifically concerned with Tengwar necessarily.  So, if Tengwar is already supported in TeX (probably in a package), this will not necessarily and immediately answer my question.  I am more concerned with being *generally* able to, basically, create *any* set of symbols and call them an alphabet/writing-system (or, more generally, a list of mathematical symbols) and then be able to reproduce them in a document using TeX as if they were any other letters/characters/symbols.  For the most part, I am not inventing mathematical symbols for new operations or anything- I just want unique variables rather than the typical Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic ones.
I am not sure if this is rephrasing the issue properly (they may be technically different), but naively, I would suppose that I would like to invent a font.

I am completely new to TeX.

Comment: I know this is just an example, but for Tengwar there actually is a package on CTAN: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex2e/contrib/tengwarscript Also, see this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/what-package-allows-elvish-in-tex

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for *METAFONT,* a program also written by Knuth and accompagnying *TeX.*  This program has a close relative *METAPOST* that can be used for drawing PostScript or SVG figures. Start here:

http://tug.org/metapost.html

I like the tutorial by André Heck, it will give you a feeling of the program.