# Latex Tengwar Combining Diacritics Not Combining

Tags: xetex, fontspec, accents

This is the code I am using to try and get nicely combined Tengwar, but it's coming out with all the combining diacritics on circles next to the characters, instead of on top of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\setmainfont{CharisSIL-R.ttf}
\newfontfamily{\telcontar}[Renderer=Graphite]{tengtelc.ttf}

\title{Langercast Podcast Notes}
\author{Wilco Jacobs \& Sam Blumire}

\begin{document}
\section{Episode 2 - }

{\telcontar      ⁘ } 

\end{document}
```

I'm expecting it to show up looking like this:

[image: Correctly Formatted Tengwar]

But it looks like this

[image: Poorly Formatted Tengwar]

I based what I am doing on what was said here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/169156/73255

But I can't seem to identify the problem, as I have done the same as them. I am using XeLaTeX

Comment: It seems that the supposed combining characters don't combine at all. Probably bad definitions in the font.

Comment: @egreg however, the other user demonstrated them to work, therefore the font definitions must b new correct

Comment: Well, I don't really believe in that answer: the usage of `inputenc` is grossly wrong, for instance. And `Rendering=Graphite` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in `fontspec`: if I install the font on my system and say `\font\telcontar="Tengwar Telcontar/GR"`, the output is correct.

Comment: @egreg unfortunately. Is a collaborative  project on sharelatex so we need to be able to link to a ttf file not rely on system fonts

Comment: The fix I suggest in my answer should work also without installing the font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in `fontspec` version 2.4a, when defining the `Renderer` key.

The following works; code is like in `fontspec-xetex.sty` and `3` has been changed into `4`, as Graphite is choice number 4.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn {fontspec-renderer}
 {
  Renderer .choice_code:n =
   {
    \int_compare:nTF {\l_keys_choice_int <= 4}% <------ was 3
     {
       \tl_set:Nv \l_fontspec_renderer_tl
        { g_fontspec_renderer_tag_ \l_keys_choice_tl }
     }
     {
      \__fontspec_warning:nx {only-luatex-feature} {Renderer=Full/Basic}
     }
   }
  ,
  Renderer .generate_choices:n = {AAT,ICU,OpenType,Graphite,Full,Basic}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newfontfamily{\telcontar}[Renderer=Graphite]{Tengwar Telcontar}


\title{Langercast Podcast Notes}
\author{Wilco Jacobs \& Sam Blumire}

\begin{document}
\section{Episode 2 - }

{\telcontar      ⁘}

\end{document}
```

Using `\newfontfamily{\telcontar}[Renderer=Graphite]{tengtelc.ttf}` is also possible.

[image]

Note that `inputenc` should *not* be loaded with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Issue raised: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/194